# How to work with multiple functions - GHUB/Lua

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I would like to know how i can go back to the first function
I wanna do  3 functions in the button 6;
First he goes to TOPX and TOPY, on the second click he goes to MIDX and MID, in the third click to the BOTX and BOTY; after this if i click again he return to the first function.

```
local  CENTER, MIDX, MIDY, BOTX, BOTY, TOPX, TOPY

----------------------Init------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
CENTER = 32767
TOPX = 59305
TOPY = 54527
MIDX = 61764
MIDY = 58683
BOTX = 64060
BOTY = 63056
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--/
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    --MIDLANE
    if  
    event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6 then
         MoveMouseTo(MIDX, MIDY)
--      PressMouseButton(1);
--          ReleaseMouseButton(1);
--              Sleep(20);
                    MoveMouseTo(MIDX, MIDY);


function OnEvent(event, arg)
    --BOTLANE
    if
    event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6 then
          MoveMouseTo(BOTX,BOTY) ; 
--      PressMouseButton(1);
--          ReleaseMouseButton(1);
                Sleep(20);
                    MoveMouseTo(CENTER, CENTER)
    --TOPLANE
    elseif
    event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
         MoveMouseTo(TOPX,TOPY) ; 
--      PressMouseButton(1);
--          ReleaseMouseButton(1);
                Sleep(20);


            end
        end
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wording is a bit confusing. You don't want to "do 3 functions". From your text I take that you want to call `MoveMouseTo` with different coordinates every third time.

So put them into a table:

```
button6Coords = {
  {x = TOPX, y = TOPY},
  {x = MIDX, y = MIDY},
  {x = BOTX, y = BOTY},
}
```

then have a global counter that increments each time you click button6.

counter6 = 0

In the event handler:

...

```
if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6 then
  counter6 = counter6 % 3 + 1
  local coords = button6Coords[counter6]            
  MoveMouseTo(coords.x, coords.y)
```

...

Comment: Sorry for the bad english, but the table just works, i'm grateful with your help, thx <3